# Execute multiple SQL commands in the SQL file in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Having issue while running the SQL file in python mysql-connector code.

In the SQL file, it contains functions, procedures and insert and create statements combined.
I am using mysql-connector-python package and here is my code:

Python Code

```
import mysql.connector

# Connect to MySQL server
con = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    user="master",
    passwd="mmmmmmm$",
    database="cl",
    port="3306"
)

# Create a cursor
cur = con.cursor(dictionary=True)

with open('a.sql', 'r') as sql_file:
    result_iterator = cur.execute(sql_file.read(), multi=True)
    
    for res in result_iterator:
        print("Running query: ", res)  # Will print out a short representation of the query
        print(f"Affected {res.rowcount} rows" )

    con.commit()  # Remember to commit all your changes!

# Close the cursor
cur.close()
```

And in SQL file

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE PROCEDURE `CONSUMER_PATH` (IN `input` INT, OUT `output` VARCHAR(128))   Begin
DECLARE _id INT;
  DECLARE _parent INT;
  DECLARE _path VARCHAR(128);

  SET `max_sp_recursion_depth` = 50;

  SELECT `id`, `parent_location_id`
  INTO _id, _parent
  FROM `locations`
  WHERE `id` = `input` and `deleted`=0 and `record_status`=1;

  IF _parent IS NULL THEN
    SET _path = _id;
  ELSE
    CALL `LOCATION_PATH`(_parent, _path);
    SELECT CONCAT(_path, ',', _id) INTO _path;
  END IF;

  SELECT _path INTO `output`;

END$$

--
-- Functions
--
CREATE FUNCTION `GET_CHILD_LOCATIONS` (`input` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(128) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci  BEGIN
  CALL `LOCATION_PATH`(`input`, @path);
  RETURN @path;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `access_controls`
--

CREATE TABLE `access_controls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `endpoint_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

While running the Python Code, it throws an error

```
se near 'DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE PROCEDURE `CONSUMER_PATH` (IN `input`...' at line 1
```

It is working fine directly in MySQL command. In python, mysql connector throws an error. Could you please guide to solve this issue.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to only execute the first line of procedure creation. You should execute the entire `CREATE PROCEDURE` query at once, otherwise it will throw an error.